# Unit testing ina Magento 2 - Mocks and Assertions

Tags: magento2, unit-tests

Open file

```
\Magento\Cms\Test\Unit\Model\PageRepositoryTest
```

and take a look at the setUp() method

```
/**
 * Initialize repository
 */
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->pageResource = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->dataObjectProcessor = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $pageFactory = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['create'])
        ->getMock();
    $pageDataFactory = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterfaceFactory::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['create'])
        ->getMock();
    $pageSearchResultFactory = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageSearchResultsInterfaceFactory::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['create'])
        ->getMock();
    $collectionFactory = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\CollectionFactory::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['create'])
        ->getMock();
    $this->storeManager = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $store = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $store->expects($this->any())->method('getId')->willReturn(0);
    $this->storeManager->expects($this->any())->method('getStore')->willReturn($store);

    $this->page = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Model\Page::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    $this->pageData = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface::class)
        ->getMock();
    $this->pageSearchResult = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageSearchResultsInterface::class)
        ->getMock();
    $this->collection = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Collection::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['getSize', 'setCurPage', 'setPageSize', 'load', 'addOrder'])
        ->getMock();

    $pageFactory->expects($this->any())
        ->method('create')
        ->willReturn($this->page);
    $pageDataFactory->expects($this->any())
        ->method('create')
        ->willReturn($this->pageData);
    $pageSearchResultFactory->expects($this->any())
        ->method('create')
        ->willReturn($this->pageSearchResult);
    $collectionFactory->expects($this->any())
        ->method('create')
        ->willReturn($this->collection);
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterfaceFactory $pageDataFactory
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $pageSearchResultFactory
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */

    $this->dataHelper = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->collectionProcessor = $this->getMockBuilder(CollectionProcessorInterface::class)
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();

    $this->repository = new PageRepository(
        $this->pageResource,
        $pageFactory,
        $pageDataFactory,
        $collectionFactory,
        $pageSearchResultFactory,
        $this->dataHelper,
        $this->dataObjectProcessor,
        $this->storeManager,
        $this->collectionProcessor
    );
}
```

Can someone explain on the concepts used here?

For example, making mocks with disabling original constructors like

```
$collectionFactory = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\CollectionFactory::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['create'])
```

and setting methods like

```
$this->collection = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Collection::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['getSize', 'setCurPage', 'setPageSize', 'load', 'addOrder'])
        ->getMock();
```

In fact, anynthig you know about unit testing will be useful for me, like what is going on in the `public function testDeleteById()` and so on and on.

Thanks in advance.